# What happens to old browsers if I use the new HTML5 tags?

Tags: html

If I use `<main>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`, `<header>`, or `<nav>` elements will there be any bad side effects when someone with IE8 tries to load my page?

Comment: Include [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to make sure they get the right styling and they'll be just like any other divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find many articles on this saying that some of these new elements are no different than generic block elements so they don’t pose any compatibility problems and all you need to ensure compatibility is to add a CSS rule to your website that causes the relevant elements to behave like block elements. Like this:

```
header, section, footer, aside, nav, main, article, figure {
    display: block; 
}
```

But IE8 and previous versions of IE pose a challenge. Any element not in the official roster of elements cannot be styled with CSS. That means we cannot make then behave like block elements or give them any formatting because they behave as if they don't exist.

Fortunately, a workaround exists for IE to recognize these new elements allowing them to be styled, and thus giving us full use of these new semantic tags. It’s a tool called [HTML5Shiv](https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv).

The trick is that calling `document.createElement("section")` will suddenly cause IE to recognize the section element. No one knows why, but it works.

But you need to make sure to call it early on in your website before any of those elements are used, otherwise it won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, (what do older browsers do?), some browsers will ignore the element. Some treat them as errors. Some will treat them as `<div>`. It's pretty much all over the place. So you need to do something and setting them to block level is the best thing you can do for them.

[Here's a longer review along with suggestions.](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/03/22/using-html5-semantic-elements-today/)